# Change in number of gauge symmetries after adding auxiliary fields to the action

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, variational-principle, gauge-invariance, variational-calculus

As per part (c) of Ex. (3.17) in Ref. 1, the number of gauge symmetries of an action does not change after adding auxiliary fields to it. But we know that a Stueckelberg field is an auxiliary field, and by definition, it adds a new gauge symmetry to the action to which it is added. Then how can the claim of part (c) of Ex. (3.17) in Ref. 1 be correct?

For convenience, I will quote the relevant part of Ex. (3.17) in Ref. 1 here. It says

> "Let $S[y^i(t), z^A(t)]$ be an action depending on auxiliary fields $z^A(t)$. That is, the equations of motion $\delta S/\delta z^A = 0$ can be solved to yield $z^A$ as a function of $y^i$ and its derivatives. We denote the solution of $\delta S/\delta z^A = 0$ by $z(y)$.
> Let $S_R[y^i(t)]$ be the action obtained by elimination of the auxiliary fields, $S_R[y^i(t)] \equiv
> S[y^i(t),z^A(y^i)(t)]$. Assume $S$ to be gauge invariant under $\delta y^i = Y^i, \delta z^A = Z^A$."

Part (c) of the exercise says

> "Prove that if $(\delta y^i,\delta z^A)$ is a complete set of gauge symmetries for $S$, then $\delta y^i$ is a complete set for $S_R$. Conversely, any complete set of gauge symmetries for $S_R$ can be extended to a complete set for $S$."

References:

1. M. Henneaux & C. Teitelboim, *Quantization of Gauge Systems,* 1994.

Answer (score -1):

Let us consider the claim of part (c) of Ex. (3.17) in Ref. 1. It says that if $(\delta y^i,\delta z^A)$ is a complete set of gauge symmetries for S, then $\delta y^i$ is a complete set for $S_R$​. Conversely, any complete set of gauge symmetries for $S_R$​ can be extended to a complete set for $S$. This means that adding or eliminating auxiliary fields doesn't change the number of gauge symmetries of an action.
However, this claim does not contradict the fact that a Stueckelberg field adds a new gauge symmetry to the action to which it is added. This is because the Stueckelberg field is not an auxiliary field in the sense of Ex. (3.17) in Ref. 1. An auxiliary field in that exercise is defined as a field whose equation of motion can be solved to yield it as a function of other fields and their derivatives. A Stueckelberg field does not satisfy this condition, as it cannot be eliminated by solving its equation of motion. Rather, it is introduced by hand to make the gauge theory massive and invariant under local transformations.
Therefore, the claim of part (c) of Ex. (3.17) in Ref. 1 does not apply to the case of adding a Stueckelberg field to an action. The Stueckelberg field is not an auxiliary field in that context, but rather a new degree of freedom that reveals a hidden symmetry of the theory.

Comment: "An auxiliary field in that exercise is defined as a field whose equation of motion can be solved to yield it as a function of other fields and their derivatives. A Stueckelberg field does not satisfy this condition, as it cannot be eliminated by solving its equation of motion." – It is not true that a Stueckelberg field cannot be eliminated by solving its equation of motion. The equation of motion of a Stueckelberg field can be solved and the field can be eliminated if required.